# Order By problem in T-Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I am getting error in following T-Sql:-

```
DECLARE @sortby VARCHAR(10)
SET @sortby='A1'

SELECT String1, String2, Date1  
FROM (
        SELECT 'A1', 'B1', CONVERT(datetime,'1 July 2010 00:01:00')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'A2', 'B2', CONVERT(datetime,'2 July 2010 00:02:00')
        ) AS a(String1,String2,Date1)
ORDER BY
        CASE 
                WHEN @sortby = 'A1' THEN String2 
                WHEN @sortby = 'B1' THEN String1
                WHEN @sortby = 'Date1' THEN Date1
        END

ERROR:Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

Its working fine only if I SET @sortby='Date1'.

Can anybody tell me if there is any syntax mistake?

Comment: hi sukhi, check my answer for problem related to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***When you write a case/when statement in T-SQL, it's critically important that you cause all return values to have the same data type. If you don't do this, you open yourself up to conversion problems. This problem can occur even if some branches of the code are never executed.***

so something as below will not work

```
DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(20)

SET @DATA = ''

SELECT CASE WHEN @DATA IS NULL THEN NULL
            WHEN @DATA = ''    THEN 'Data is empty'
            WHEN 0=1           THEN 1
            END
```

More with solution : http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/11/sql-server-casewhen-return-type.html

Answer (score 1):

Separate your column names with commas in the order-by clause.

```
ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @sortby = 'A1' THEN String2 END,
        CASE WHEN @sortby = 'B1' THEN String1 END,
        CASE WHEN @sortby = 'Date1' THEN Date1 END
```

Comment: Ok Now Its working fine but can u tell me the problem in the statement i posted earlier having single case statement

Comment: A single case can only have a single type. Your case statement had an implicit type of datetime, because the last column referenced was a datetime. The other columns in your statement could not be converted to datetime, which is what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
DECLARE @sortby VARCHAR(10) 
SET @sortby='Date1' 

SELECT String1, String2, Date1   
FROM ( 
        SELECT 'A1', 'B1', CONVERT(datetime,'1 July 2010 00:01:00') 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'A2', 'B2', CONVERT(datetime,'2 July 2010 00:02:00') 
        ) AS a(String1,String2,Date1) 
ORDER BY 
        CASE  
                WHEN @sortby = 'A1' THEN String2  
                WHEN @sortby = 'B1' THEN String1 
                WHEN @sortby = 'Date1' THEN convert(datetime,cast(Date1 as varchar(20))) 
        END
```

Comment: I have written Its working fine only if I SET @sortby='Date1'. It gives error if i SET @sortby='A1'.

Comment: saperate case statement for each column is the only and perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast the last value as varchar, otherwise the type for the order by clause is interpreted as a date:

```
DECLARE @sortby VARCHAR(10)
SET @sortby='A1'

SELECT String1, String2, Date1  
FROM (
        SELECT 'A1', 'B1', CONVERT(datetime,'1 July 2010 00:01:00')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'A2', 'B2', CONVERT(datetime,'2 July 2010 00:02:00')
        ) AS a(String1,String2,Date1)
ORDER BY
        CASE 
                WHEN @sortby = 'A1' THEN String2 
                WHEN @sortby = 'B1' THEN String1
                WHEN @sortby = 'Date1' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date1, 112)
        END
```

Comment: WHEN @sortby = 'Date1' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date1, 1) will do string comparision for date coulmn instead of date time. it will not give correct sorted data.. check it for 1 july and 1 Aug..

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and used the wrong date format. It's fixed now, I'm using ISO (12) this will sort correctly.